# push notification not working for Push.payload() where as it is working for Push.alert()

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I am sending push notification from my java code to ios devices using javapns. but I am not getting push notification for Push.payload() and its working fine with Push.alert().
Am I missing something?
my code is

```
Payload payload = new PushNotificationPayload();
payload.addCustomDictionary("param", ConsumerConf.GSON.toJson(message.getMsgInfo()));
List<PushedNotification> pushedNotifications = Push.payload(payload, certficate, password, true, appDeviceIds);
```

here my created payload object is

```
{
    "apsDictionary": {
        "map": {}
    },
    "payload": {
        "map": {
            "aps": {
                "map": {}
            },
            "param": "{\"suid\":12,\"eid\":1626,\"oid\":1,\"accountId\":7491}"
        }
    },
    "characterEncoding": "UTF-8",
    "expiry": 86400,
    "payloadSizeEstimatedWhenAdding": false,
    "preSendConfiguration": 0
}
```

My payload object doesn't contains alert/sound fields in aps.
Is this because of that?

Please help me out here.

Comment: In which iOS version are you testing this? If it's older than iOS8, the payload size is limited to 256 bytes, which it seems you may be exceeding (though I didn't count the bytes).

Comment: I am testing on iOS8

Comment: even I am getting true for pushedNotification.isSuccessful()